# Why can a double value be initialized as a word?

Tags: java, class, constructor, initialization, double

For example, the class is `Car`:

```
public Car(double speed)
```

But you can initialize it, like:

```
Car honda = new Car(speed);
```

I thought `double` was a decimal?

Comment: `speed` can be a `double` variable. In that case you can use it instead of a `double` literal like `90.25` (think of `double speed = 90.25; honda = new Car(speed);`)

Comment: `double` is floating-point. This is extremely basic. There is no 'word' here. Possibly you mean 'variable', which is also extremely basic.

Comment: You need to give us the full context, best as [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When I just paste your initialization into my Eclipse (IDE), I get *speed cannot be resolved to a variable*, which obviously doesn’t happen to you.

Comment: I suggest working through a Java tutorial doing exercises as you go along. I work through a tutorial or book, starting at the beginning, whenever I'm learning a programming language. You should have been introduced to identifiers and their declarations before needing to understand a constructor call.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few misconceptions here.

Concerning this:

```
  public Car(double speed) { ... }  // A
  ...
  Car honda = new Car(speed); // B
```

> Why can a double value be initialized as a word?

The `speed` in statement `B` is not a "word".  (In fact, there no "word" type in Java.  Perhaps you meant `String`?   But this is not an example of a `String` either.)

In fact, occurrences of `speed` in declaration `A` and statement `B` are *identifiers*.  And in  these contexts, those identifiers must be the names of *variables*.

<sup>(They will be a different `speed` variables.  The `speed` variable defined in declaration `A` won't be the one that is used in `B`.  That's OK.  In Java, the same name can be used for different things, provided that the names are declared in the respective contexts.)</sup>

In fact, `new Car(speed)` means: "create a `Car`, passing the **value** of the `speed` variable to the constructor".

We cannot see the declaration for the `speed` variable that is used in statement `B` is used.  However, if the code compiles, the type of that `speed` variable must be compatible with `double`.  Either the type is `double`, or it must be convertible to `double` using one of the conversions that the Java language permits.  (It could be an `int` or a `Double` for example.  But not a `String`!)

Now we could write this:

```
Car honda = new Car("speed");   // incorrect !
```

This attempts to pass the word "speed" (represented as a `String`) to the `Car` constructor.  Of course it won't work. Java won't attempt to convert a string to a number ... and this string isn't a number anyway.

---

> I thought `double` was a decimal?

No.  It is NOT decimal.  Decimal means base 10, and Java `double` is NOT a base 10 representation.

In fact, `double` is a primitive binary (base 2) *floating point* type.

Java does not have any primitive decimal types (either fixed point or floating point) but there is a Java SE class called `BigDecimal` which is an indefinite precision floating point decimal type.